# Sum of element of all subset of size k

Tags: algorithms

Efficient way to find the sum of all elements of all subsets of size $k$ for a given set $s=\{1,2\dots,n\}$ ($n\ge k$). Example:

$s=\{1,2,3\}$, $k=2$.

$s_1=\{1,2\}:\;1+2=3$
$s_2=\{1,3\}:\;1+3=4$
$s_3=\{2,3\}:\;2+3=5$.

And the sum is $3+4+5=12$.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? Are you looking for some way which does not need to enumerate all the subsets of size $k$ (which I doubt)?

Comment: Is there any method?@hengxin

Comment: Is it possible to store the value of s1 ,s2,and so on in a array?Can you provide me the solution?@hengxin

Comment: I missed the last "sum" part. Now there is a way. See the answer given by @David Richerby.

Comment: I don't see a question in this post; it's a problem statement. What *is* your question? What are your thoughts, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 4):

Every element of $s$ appears in the same number of $k$-subsets. So just figure out how many that is and multiply $\sum_{x\in s}x$ by that number.

Comment: I am not getting your explanation .Can you please explain more?@david

Comment: In the example in the question, each element of $s$ appears in two different subsets. So the total over all the subsets is just twice the total of $s$.

Comment: David explained it rightly but for k<n/2 where n are the no of elements in the original set.(think about nCk, that will tell you how many subsets of k size are possible)

Comment: If i need only s1 ,s2,s3 and so on and want to store them into an array ,what will i have to do?

Comment: @hunch It works even for $k>n/2$. For example, for $k=n-1$, each element of the set appears in $n-1$ subsets.

Comment: @DavidRicherby , yeah,you are right, that will work, it slipped through my mind.

Comment: What will i have to do if i want to store indivisual sum of each subset of size k?@hunch and david

Comment: Your question asked for an efficient way to compute the sum of the size-$k$ subsets. I answered that question. If you want some other question answering, please ask a separate question. However, if you want to store all the sums of size-$k$ subsets, how could you do anything other than compute them all and store them?